# Issue with prepare for Segue and AccessoryButtonTappedForRowWith

Tags: swift3

After clicking on a accessoryButton in TableView, it will redirect me first to ***PrepareforSegue*** function and then to ***accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith*** Function which creating error in my code.

Please have a look into my code:

```
var indexPathAccessory: Int?  

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith indexPath: IndexPath) {
    indexPathAccessory = indexPath.row
}
```

***indexPathAccessory*** contains the value of row where ***Accessorybutton*** was clicked.
The second function is:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Add" {
        let nc = segue.destination as! UINavigatorController
        controller = nc.topViewController as! AVC
        //Comment 1
        controller.name = span[indexPathAccessory]
        //Comment 2

        controller.delegate = self
    }
}
```

I am getting error cause after clicking on ***accessorybutton***, it is redirecting me to ***prepareforSegue*** function first and then to ***accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith*** and due to value of ***indexPathAccessory*** which still nil, I am getting this error

Will it be possible to jump first on ***accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith*** to get the value of ***indexPathAccessory*** and then to ***prepareForSegue***?
if yes, problem will be solved.

I tried to add one test to return if ***indexPathAccessory*** is nil.
application run without error but not in a proper way:
I can see that *controller.name* is equal to ***"test"***, but when I am on AVC View controller, ***name*** became ***nil***

Any advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it worked by deleting the ***accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith*** function, and adding the following code to ***prepareforSegue*** functions:

```
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: sender as! UITableViewCell) {

            controller.beamName = "Test"

            indexSpanAccessory = indexPath.row
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the solution can be - remove the segue from the storyboard which causes the control going out of your hand and write the performSegue inside your `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith` method.

Comment: I tried before but I did not success how to send the name and the delegate to the next view controller !!!